# Maximize a simple expression based on EuclideanDistance takes too long

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum, distance

Do you know if there is a mistake in this command syntax? It is very simple and still it takes too long. I cannot obtain any result at all:

```
Maximize[{(EuclideanDistance[{a, d}, {b, e}]+EuclideanDistance[{b, e}, {c, f}]+EuclideanDistance[{c, f}, {a, d}]), 0<=a<=1,0<=d<=1,0<=b<=1,0<=e<=1,0<=c<=1,0<=f<=1}, {a,d,b,e,c,f}]
```

Comment: This is not a simple optimization problem:a nonlinear and nondifferentiable target function in 6 variables. The result of `NMaximize[{(EuclideanDistance[{a, d}, {b, e}] + 
    EuclideanDistance[{b, e}, {c, f}] + 
    EuclideanDistance[{c, f}, {a, d}]), 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= d <= 1, 
  0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= e <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, 0 <= f <= 1}, {a, d, b, e, c,
   f}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]` suggests an exact solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scene = GeometricScene[{ad, be, cf},
   {Line[{ad, be}], Line[{be, cf}], Line[{cf, ad}]}];

RandomInstance[scene, RandomSeeding -> 4]
```

[image]

Maximizing the sum of the distances

```
{max, arg} = 
 NMaximize[{(EuclideanDistance[{a, d}, {b, e}] + 
      EuclideanDistance[{b, e}, {c, f}] + EuclideanDistance[{c, f}, {a, d}]), 
    0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= d <= 1, 0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= e <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, 
    0 <= f <= 1}, {a, d, b, e, c, f}] /. x_Real :> RootApproximant[x]

(* {2 + Sqrt[2], {a -> 1, d -> 1, b -> 1, e -> 0, c -> 0, f -> 1}} *)
```

Equivalently, maximizing the perimeter of the triangle

```
{max2, arg2} = 
 NMaximize[{Perimeter[Triangle[{{a, d}, {b, e}, {c, f}}]], 0 <= a <= 1, 
    0 <= d <= 1, 0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= e <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, 0 <= f <= 1}, {a, d, 
    b, e, c, f}] /. x_Real :> RootApproximant[x]

(* {2 + Sqrt[2], {a -> 1, d -> 1, b -> 1, e -> 0, c -> 0, f -> 1}} *)
```

As expected, the results are identical

```
{max, arg} === {max2, arg2}

(* True *)

Show[GeometricScene[{ad -> {a, d}, be -> {b, e}, cf -> {c, f}} /. arg,
   {Line[{ad, be}], Line[{be, cf}], Line[{cf, ad}]}]["Graphics"], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]